# Unicode and Scientific Word/Workplace

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, scientific-workplace

I am working in a group whose leader uses Scientific Workplace (SWP) 5.5. Most other people in the group do not use this software and since MacKichan (spelling?) went bankrupt, there is no way to legally obtain this software anymore (version 6+ can be downloaded freely but that one apparently works quite a bit differently).

The problem is that when somebody writes a TeX document in UTF8 encoding (\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}) containing accented characters such as áéíóúűő etc, when SWP opens these documents, the text appears garbled. When the group leader works on the document in SWP and sends it back, the text gets irreparably messed up for us as well.

As an example, the document

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
 Ó, ió, áció, ráció ez egy üledékes meghűlt őrületes degeneráció
\end{document}
```

Looks like this: [image: pic]

when opened in SWP (this is in version 6+ since I only have access to that one, but it behaves the same in SWP 5.5 as well).

If I open the TeX file saved by SWP if the original file is saved over, the document reads

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=LATEX.DLL}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2890}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Thursday, January 26, 2023 15:37:55}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}

\input{tcilatex}

\begin{document}


\~{A}\textquotedblleft , i\~{A}%
%TCIMACRO{\U{b3}}%
%BeginExpansion
${{}^3}$%
%EndExpansion
, \~{A}\textexclamdown ci\~{A}%
%TCIMACRO{\U{b3}}%
%BeginExpansion
${{}^3}$%
%EndExpansion
, r\~{A}\textexclamdown ci\~{A}%
%TCIMACRO{\U{b3} }%
%BeginExpansion
${{}^3}$
%EndExpansion
ez egy \~{A}%
%TCIMACRO{\U{bc}}%
%BeginExpansion
$\frac14$%
%EndExpansion
led\~{A}\copyright kes megh\AA \pm lt \AA `r\~{A}%
%TCIMACRO{\U{bc}}%
%BeginExpansion
$\frac14$%
%EndExpansion
letes degener\~{A}\textexclamdown ci\~{A}%
%TCIMACRO{\U{b3}}%
%BeginExpansion
${{}^3}$%
%EndExpansion
\end{document}
```

We have also checked that if the group leader creates a tex file with SWP that contains accented characters, they will be saved in the .tex file in "TeX style", eg. é as `\'e` .

This makes collaboration rather difficult since we essentially have to redo a lot of work when accents are involved.

I am at a complete loss how to solve this. I figured it would be possible to make SWP use UTF8 encoding somehow and the user manual states that SWP will interpret inputenc in the preamble. Yet this does not appear to be the case as the sample tex file above as inputenc called with the utf8 argument and SWP still does not handle it well.

Some indirect solution could also be OK, for example if I could save a tex file written with unicode characters in a way that the accented letters are converted into TeX accents.

Comment: you could save the file as latin1 (iso-8859-1) not utf-8 and use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` a very 1990's choice, should make your leaders feel at home.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What do you mean concretely? If I save a .tex file containing accented characters in [latin1] then I won't be able to compile it without garbling the text like SWP does it. Are you suggesting removing the accented characters as well in favour of eg. `\'e` ? If so, it is workable but very inconvenient and I am hoping for a better solution.

Comment: latin1 has (almost) all the accents used in western europe and was the default encoding for most editors and for latex until 2018,  oh But I think this is Hugarian so latin2 would be better, but the same idea latin-x encodings are fixed 1-byte encodings of 256 letters unlike utf-8 which is a variable length encoding. Your editor should be able to save the file in latin-2 and then declare latin2 to inputenc.  keeping all accents

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok then I have a tex noob question: what does it mean to save a file in a given encoding? I thought the inputenc line was the only determinator of font encoding, i.e. changing utf8 to latinx in the inputenc line is sufficient.

Comment: no inputenc just declares to latex how the file is encoded.  It has to be correct. You could re-enode the file to a different encoding but you then need to tell latex so that it can read it. If you just add `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to a utf-8 encoded file, latex will take each byte of the unicode character and treat it as a latin1 character and you will get nonsense out.

Comment: What does it happen when you open in SWP 6.0 a file that was previously created and saved with SWP 5.5? If it opens without errors, a solution would for those that don't have SWP 5.5 to use SWP 6.0.

Comment: swp5.5 is a factastic program, far better than swp6. but it has a few anachronisms you have to deal with. before you open a file containing umlauts in swp5.5, you could open it in notepad++ and select encoding/convert to ansi. i made myself a little powershell script to deal with this and a few other annoyances.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that the document your project leader saves from SWP55 contains accented characters. If you import it into SWP 6 then the characters with accents have the correct form, eg. É or Á. If you export it from SWP 6 then you get a file in utf8 provided that the preamble is supplemented by the commands \usepackage{t1enc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain better what you mean? Can you show a TeX code?